# How to figure it out on which mistake i made when i run npm run build?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, single-page-application, npm-build

I'm quite new to this VueJS things. And this is my first App creating a SPA with separated server-side app. I faced the problem right before deploying my app on a shared hosting. Simply, when i run "npm run build", it return with an error in which i don't even know the cause. Here is the error i faced.

[first img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5BqN.png)

[second img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2blAe.png)

Please help me resolve this issues, i know there are jquery errors, but i think those are not the problems

Answer (score 0):

You have es-lint checker. It checks unused vars so you have unused variables inside these listed components like from and to. You should remove these variable from your components.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors come from your linter (probably eslint) which is a tool designed to ensure consistence and code quality : in your case it mainly complains about declared variables that are not used anywhere else in your code and `$` being undefined (I guess you're trying to use jquery which you should not be doing in a vue project anyway)

On the images you posted you have all necessary infos : the title of each block tells you in which file the error is (for example `App.vue` in the first image) and then you have line/column to locate precisely where you need to adjust :)

Note that you can configure your linter (what should be error/warning/skipped out) overwriting (or creating if it doesn't exist) a config file at the root of your project (if you use eslint for example, you can create a `.eslintrc` file). See [the config part of the official doc](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/)